# Mouse click maximize my object...?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, resize

In xcode whenever I make a single mouse click on its bounds in order to resize it always expands to the maximum bounds.

Example: I have an imageview with an image attached to it. The image is 640x1366, but the imageview is only 30x30. I select the imageview and want to start dragging its boundary points in order to resize it, but when I press any of its boundary points the imageview is instantly set to 640x1366 since the image connected to it has those dimensions.

I have no idea why it's like this, because it wasn't when I started developing. This happens on any kind of object, so this affects labels, textviews etc. What I have to do now is to type in the values for x and y manually and do trial and error in order to get something the correct size, which is frustrating as hell.

Does anyone know if this is an option or how I can fix this?

Sincerely,
ClockWise